Watch for file changes and send the data through websocket
I have an endpoint in my python fast api and whenver the frontend connects to it, I want to listen for changes on a specific file stored in the temporary directory of the system. I am using watch dog, but I am not able to make it work it, its just not sending any message on changes :-
class LogFileEventHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def __init__(self, websocket: WebSocket, videoId: str):
        self.websocket = websocket
        self.videoId = videoId

    async def on_modified(self, event):
        if event.src_path.endswith(f"log_{self.videoId}.txt"):
            logFile = os.path.join(temp_dir, f"log_{self.videoId}.txt")
            with open(logFile, "r") as file:
                content = file.read()
                # Send file content to WebSocket
                await self.websocket.send_text(content)

@router.websocket("/logs")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket, videoId: str = Query(...)):
    await manager.connect(websocket)

    print(f" Client connected: {websocket.client.host}")
 
    # Create event handler and observer
    event_handler = LogFileEventHandler(websocket, videoId)
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, temp_dir, recursive=False)
    observer.start()

    try:
        while True:
            try:
                data = await websocket.receive_json()
            except RuntimeError:
                break  
    except WebSocketDisconnect:
        print(f"Client disconnected: {websocket.client.host}") 
        manager.disconnect(websocket)
        observer.stop()
        observer.join()


How do you run your server? Do you have several workers?

Does this answer your question?

@YuriiMotov I used unicorn to run my server. uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 5000 --reload .
When the user connects with the websocket, it passes a videoId as the query, I want to check for any changed on that videoId's txt file and and send the change to the websocket

@Chris I honestly don't get that, I am not sure what problem I am facing in the code

Try adding print('modified') right before the line await self.websocket.send_text(content). Does it print something in the console when you change the file?

@YuriiMotov I am getting the following warning and no it didn't print the 'modified' :-
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'LogFileEventHandler.on_modified' was never awaited
  {
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback


The problem is that watchdog library doesn't support asyncio. And it just calls on_modified method instead of awaiting it.
You should look for an alternative to watchdog that supports asyncio.
Also, you can try the approach, explained in this gist: https://gist.github.com/mivade/f4cb26c282d421a62e8b9a341c7c65f6
